# Javascript: How to spy on superagent with Jasmine?

Tags: ajax, unit-testing, jasmine, superagent

I'm using the superagent ajax library for an app, and I'm trying to write some unit tests for it.  I've got a class which looks like this:

```
someClass = {
  getData: function(){
    _this = this;
    superagent.get('/some_url').end(function(res){
      if(res.body){
        _this.data = res.body
      }
     });
   });
 }
```

How do I write a Jasmine test to spy on the `_this.data = res.body` call? Setting up a spy with `and.callThrough()` on `getData` isn't working.  I don't want to actually *call* the URL in question; I'm just trying to test that if it gets data, it does something with it.

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to point out that the title sounds like a question that some innocent young agent would ask as they try to figure out what some 00's mission is. Presumably, they named their microdrone Jasmine.

Answer (score 3):

```
spyOn(superagent, 'get').and.callFake(function(url) {
  return {
    end: function(cb) {
      //null for no error, and object to mirror how a response would look.
      cb(null, {body: data});
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bror's answer works perfectly. To add something to his answer, when we need to add another superagent function (like `set`) to the `spyOn` method, you can use as follows.

```
spyOn(superagent, 'get').and.callFake(function(url) {
  return {
      set: function() {
        return {
          end: function(cb) {
            //null for no error, and object to mirror how a response would look.
            cb(null, {body: data});
          }
        }
     }
});
```

Here, the set function is used to set headers to the request.

Comment: If we chain multiple methods like `get().query().headers().timeout().end()`, how do we spy on the inner most `get` call? Create a chain like the one you showed in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There's another good solution here, which is to abstract out the anonymous function:

```
someClass = {
  getData: function(){
    _this = this;
    superagent.get('/some_url').end(this.handleAjax);
  },

  handleAjax: function(res){
    if(res.body){
      _this.data = res.body
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can test the handleAjax function discretely and with simple tests; and also stub superagent as you only need to check a method `.end()` is called on it with a particular value.

Anonymous functions are [problematic for other reasons](https://toddmotto.com/avoiding-anonymous-javascript-functions/) than just testing so this is a good refactor

Answer (score 0):

Say it's a patch, first make a mock patch return value:

```
this.mockPatchObject = {
      set: () => {
        return {
          end: (cb: any) => {
            cb(null, {body: 'etc'});
          },
        };
      },
    };
```

then return it as the value of patch:

```
this.superagentSpy = spyOn(request,'patch').and.returnValue(this.mockPatchObject);
```

then spy on the set function of the "mock" patch object:

```
this.superagentSetSpy = spyOn(this.mockPatchObject, 'set');
```